# How to simplify long subscription into multiple observers/drivers

Tags: swift3, rx-swift

How can I transform this (simplified for clarity, if you can believe it)…

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    viewModel.track
        .asObservable()
        .subscribe(onNext: { upcomingTrack in

            self.showLoadingView()

            upcomingTrack.fetchYoutubeData()
                .observeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(globalConcurrentQueueQOS: .background))
                .subscribe(onNext: { metadata in
                    if metadata.isInvalid {
                        viewModel.skip(upcomingTrack)
                        return
                    }

                    XCDYouTubeClient.default().getVideoWithIdentifier(metadata.youTubeId, completionHandler: { (video, error) in
                        if video != nil {

                            if let streamUrls = video?.streamURLs,
                                let streamUrl = streamUrls[NSNumber(value: XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.HD720.rawValue)]
                                    ?? streamUrls[NSNumber(value: XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.medium360.rawValue)] {

                                //  DO STUFF WITH streamURL
                                //  DO STUFF WITH upcomingTrack
                                self.hideLoadingView()
                            } else {
                                // ☠️ Not happy about this duplication
                                viewModel.skip(upcomingTrack)
                            }
                        } else {
                            viewModel.skip(upcomingTrack)
                        }
                    })

                }).addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
        }).addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
}
```

…into something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    viewModel.trackBeganLoading
        .drive(onNext: { _ in
            self.showLoadingView()
    }

    viewModel.loadedTrack
        .drive(onNext: { upcomingTrack in
            //  DO STUFF WITH upcomingTrack
            self.hideLoadingView()
        })
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

    viewModel.streamURL
        .drive(onNext: { url in
            //  DO STUFF WITH streamURL
        })
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}
```

Apologies in advance for the open-ended nature of this question. I'm not even sure where to start unravelling this beast!

Comment: The idea of using emoji in comments is brilliant!

Comment: Thanks! Credit goes in part to LaunchBar, which allows me to enter emoji mouselessly. 